# Enviar e-mail sem que apareça na caixa de enviados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, envio-de-email

Não quero que apareça no e-mail da imobiliária esses itens enviados.

```
            string emailOrigem = imobiliaria.Email;
            string password = imobiliaria.Senha;
            string html = getBody(dados); //aqui serve pra formata o html

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.Subject = dados.Assunto;
                msg.From = new MailAddress(emailOrigem);

                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Body = html;

                if (dados.Modelo.Contains("indicar"))
                {
                    EmailTemplate plate = (EmailTemplate)dados;
                    bool temEmail = !string.IsNullOrEmpty((dados as EmailTemplate).EmailIndicado);
                    if (temEmail)
                    {
                        msg.To.Add(plate.EmailIndicado);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(Email da imobiliaria aq));
                }

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                //smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(emailOrigem, password);
                smtp.Credentials = nc;
                smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Você não tem controle sobre isso. Pode até ter alguma API da Google que permita manipular as caixas, mas é outra tecnologia.

Comment: então de qualquer maneira vai aparecer?... blz cara vlww

Comment: Desta forma vai. Só com APIs poderia manipular as caixas, mesmo assim não estou dizendo que elas permitem isso, apenas que é uma possibilidade. Mas se for usar a API acho pouco provável que precise usar o servidor de e-mail.

Comment: Era só algo pouco comodo, se eu nao to enganado eles criam email pra isso. enfim. vlw cara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tecnologia que está sendo usada é para conectar a um servidor SMTP e enviar a mensagem. Nada mais que isso. Não há como controlar como o provedor manipulará as mensagens.

No caso da Google eu sei que tem uma API para fazer isso. Mas é outra coisa completamente diferente. E se for para usá-lo provavelmente deve fazer todo processo por ela e não pelo servidor SMTP.

[Exemplo de comando da API para mandar a mensagem para a lixeira](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/trash).